# how to setup this gui

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-jde

Im having quite a difficult time setting up this GUI

[image]

As you can see in the picture i need to have several clickable items and i dont know how to do it. So i thought i could make one different `VerticalFieldManager` representing the white background. But it looks impossible to have more than two `VerticalFieldManager` over the main manager. So i thought i could use a `LabelField` and change the background color to white (it didnt work either) and on top of it put clickable labels and clickable textField but i dont get the background `VerticalFieldManager` to repeat it self and put itself under the previous one with a slight margin between them. Anyways, can you guys give me ideas on how to accomplish this GUI, what to use as background.

Thanks in advance and have a nice one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following layout

[image]

- Screen delegate should be `VerticalFieldManager`
- Each item should be `VerticalFieldManager` as well
- The body of the item itself should be `RichTextField`
- The rest of the clickable elements you mentioned should be clickable `Label`s.
- You will have to use `HorizontalFieldManager`s as well. One for the top panel and one for the bottom panel. Check the `JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager` from the advanced UI libarary.

As for clickable label - it is easy to implement one. Search SO for "[blackberry] clickable label". You can also check the `BaseButtonField` and `BitmapButtonField` provided in BlackBerry advanced UI library and available [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276).